# Redirect domain dns to different server by country ip

Tags: apache, dns, reverse-dns, google-cloud-dns

I have one domian with this name "example.com"
but i want any time user come to my domain redirect to different server by user country ip

user ip = 192.168.1.1 : USA Go To "example.com" with ip => 127.0.0.1 in USA

user ip = 192.168.1.2 : Canada Go To "example.com" with ip => 127.0.0.2 Canada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set up a [HTTP(S) Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/)

The following quote was taken from the above link:

> **Creating a cross-region load balancer**
>
> You can use a global IP address that can intelligently route users
>   based on proximity. For example, if you set up instances in North
>   America, Europe, and Asia, users around the world will be
>   automatically sent to the backends closest to them, assuming those
>   instances have enough capacity. If the closest instances do not have
>   enough capacity, cross-region load balancing automatically forwards
>   users to the next closest region.

See the following link for a guide on how to set this up

[Creating Cross-Region Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/cross-region-example)

Answer (score 0):

Answering via mobile phone device.

First off you will need a database of ip addresses to country, i looked into this some years ago and found they are charged, some are free but its accuracy arent as good as premium databases

Then once you have this
You can either do a database table of country iso code to a php or asp page

Or
You could do a switch statement on an isolated php or asp page that you include into the page, allowing you to reuse elsewhere in your website  without endlessly copying and pasting scripts